# Is it bad practice to create a custom winforms app as an installer?

Tags: c#, installation

I can't find an installer on the market I like that's opensource or free. Sure I would love to use Install shield, but my project needs to finish under budget.

I was thinking about creating a custom win forms app to handle the install, is this acceptable practice. Or should I be creating a custom MSI?

If MSI is the route, what tools should I use?

Essentially I need to perform the following in the installer:

1. Create an IIS Application
2. Set permissions
3. Install a console app
4. Create a scheduled task

then when patching

1. Replace bin dll's for IIS app

The built in installers provided by Microsoft are not flexible enough to creat self standing IIS applications.

Comment: You may have skipped over NSIS...

Comment: @Charles, alright nevermind I found it, but it seems like a bit of a time investment, do you recommend it?

Comment: I have zero experience with it as a developer; I mention it as an end user only and knowing it's free to use, thus submitting it as a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: For scheduling tasks I have resorted to the "at" command in a batch file as a post install event in am MSI.  Hack'ish, but it worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MSI is the recommendation from Microsoft to install *anything* .

Sure there are simpler cases where xcopy deployment is fine, or where you can have your own installer.  But In complex cases, users want the auditing and uninstall capabilities, the familiar UI, the pre-req checking (among other things) that comes with MSI.

You can customize the MSI-based install that is produced with Visual Studio.

I normally write scripts using Javascript to do the customization, and then set the Javascript script as a "custom install action".

[image]

Comment: How about patching? Does the MSI route patch versions easily?

Comment: what does patching mean?  You can design the MSI so that it patches older versions.  You can also use a custom action to do anything exotic.

Answer (score 2):

[WiX](http://wix.sourceforge.net/) has Visual Studio integration and is not too painful so far as an MSI builder goes that is more fully customizable than the built in setup projects.

Answer (score 1):

If you can do it, then just create your own installer, as an executable.  It could either download the file to be installed or they have downloaded a zip file and then run the executable, which will have all the files to use for the installation.

I have done that before, as I needed to do some steps that VS2003 couldn't do, and the users didn't seem to mind running the executable.

Just make certain you have some sort of version in a file or registry, so that you can tell if you need to update, as there may be some extra steps in updating between version 1.2 and 3.8, if some people don't update that often.

While your installing is running, make certain to give good information as to what you are doing and how far along you are, that will help people feel better.

Answer (score 1):

You can create Windows Installer by Visual Studio, and add [custom actions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368066%28VS.85%29.aspx) to do what you want.

Comment: unfortunately, the built in Microsoft stuff, doesn't create full blown IIS applications, it installs to virtual directories

Answer (score 0):

I have had good success with Inno Setup.  It uses a pascal like language and has a GUI helper app called ISTool.  It's free/OSS and well documented.  I can't imagine having to write mine own installation program when there are so many options out there.  Other tools that I've looked at are NSIS (already mentioned), WIX (Microsoft open sourced MSI building tool), and of course the VS Setup Project with custom scripts.